# Java Serializing: One object per file

Tags: java, serialization

For this specific project I need to serialize my entity layer (made of POJO's) to files. As I have the need for updating specific objects I would like to use one file per serialized object.

Example: Customer --ArrayList-> Order --ArrayList-> Product

When I edit a customer, and then serialize it using the java.io.Serializable interface, all fields, and their fields (**please correct me if wrong**), get serialized.

How would I apply serialization in such a way that only one object per file is used? I already have given each object a uniqe UUID which is used as filename when serializing.

If there are any frameworks that do File based ORM, that would be even better ;)

Comment: why do you believe you would need one object per file ?
Some size issue or ?

Comment: There are frameworks which allow you to use a Map of Serializable objects but they don't use one file per object as that is rather inefficient.

Comment: I would like to lock specific objects when they are being edited, so using single files I could lock a specific file (and thus object) by placing a lockfile next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with such framework. 
What you can do is use other frameworks such as apache [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) in order to perform the following recursive algorithm: 
A. For each object gets its properties (assuming the object is a Java bean).
B. For each primitive field , write all primitives to file (you can use reflection to determine if a field is primitive or not). 
C. For each non primitive file, write a special section in the file, pointing to the file name that will contain the object that is the value of the field. 
D. Call recursively the algorithm for each non primitive field.
Similar approach can be done for collections - 
HashMap, ArrayList and others. 
The serializing code for the primitive elements can be the code provided by @Anshu

Answer (score 0):

You can always read and write serializable objects using `readObject` and `writeObject`. Following is the example code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class ExerciseSerializable {

  public static void main(String... aArguments) {
    //create a Serializable List
    List<String> quarks = Arrays.asList(
      "up", "down", "strange", "charm", "top", "bottom"
    );

    //serialize the List
    //note the use of abstract base class references

    try{
      //use buffering
      OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream( "quarks.ser" );
      OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream( file );
      ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream( buffer );
      try{
        output.writeObject(quarks);
      }
      finally{
        output.close();
      }
    }  
    catch(IOException ex){
      fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform output.", ex);
    }

    //deserialize the quarks.ser file
    //note the use of abstract base class references

    try{
      //use buffering
      InputStream file = new FileInputStream( "quarks.ser" );
      InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream( file );
      ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream ( buffer );
      try{
        //deserialize the List
        List<String> recoveredQuarks = (List<String>)input.readObject();
        //display its data
        for(String quark: recoveredQuarks){
          System.out.println("Recovered Quark: " + quark);
        }
      }
      finally{
        input.close();
      }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
      fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input. Class not found.", ex);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
      fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input.", ex);
    }
  }

  // PRIVATE //

  //Use Java's logging facilities to record exceptions.
  //The behavior of the logger can be configured through a
  //text file, or programmatically through the logging API.
  private static final Logger fLogger =
    Logger.getLogger(ExerciseSerializable.class.getPackage().getName())
  ;
}
```

Comment: This is not what the person asking had in mind. He asked how he can take an object graph and make sure all its nodes are kept in separate files.

Comment: Using this I could indeed write my own (de)serializer, this might be a solution.

Comment: peterrus - I think the complete solution should include both of our answers - a. Use @Anshu answer in order to perform the actual serialization of primtive fields per object. b. use my algorithm in order to perform DFS like traversal on object graph, and keep each object in its own file, as you wanted.